# Point to previous value without decrementing pointer

Tags: c++, pointers

This is a pretty simple question.

Basically, say I have two iterators, `it1` and `it2`. Given a value for `it1`, I want to define `it2` to point to a location one address earlier. It would be cool if I could do it in one line, like:

```
vector<int>::iterator it2 = --it1;
```

However, this simultaneously decrements it1, so I have to re-increment it1.

```
vector<int>::iterator it2 = --it1;
++it1;
```

If these two lines are involved in a performance-intensive loop, I will have lots of `it1` going back and forth for no good reason, just to define `it2`. On the other hand, if I do:

```
vector<int>::iterator it2 = it1;
--it2;
```

This is also slightly less than optimal as it involves two steps. Is there a way to do it in one?

Comment: This type of iterator could be implemented just as a int*. In this case, the code is so simple that the compiler could optimize the results getting the same result. Even if you write `it2=it1-1 the compiler could transform the expresion to use operator--

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're looking for [`std::prev`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/prev):

```
vector<int>::iterator it2 = std::prev(it1);
```

For `vector`'s iterator, pointers and random access iterator in general, you can also use operator `-`:

```
vector<int>::iterator it2 = it - 1;
```

Comment: Just as a side warning... be sure that you don't accidentally walk your iterator off the beginning of your vector (and dereference it).